# Splitting polyline by points using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, line, order

I have a layer containing a curved polyline and I would like to split it at multiple point locations, which I have in another layer. In ArcGIS 10.2, I can do this with the tool "Split Line at Point". It is working, but now I have a chaotic attribute table. The order of each feature in the table is not the same as it is geographically.

How can I order the polylines geographically?

1. The line is curved at many sections, so order only by latitude or longitude is not possible. (I think that this method is applied by ArcGIS, because the order of the points for splitting is the correct.)
2. I have tried it with searching for the same End_X and Start_X, but it seems that they have not always the same coordinates.

[image: Splitted Polyline with Object ID of sections]
[image: Splitted Polyline with Object ID, splitting points with ID]

Comment: Can you edit your Question to explain why you want split this polyline, please?  My suspicion is that [**Linear Referencing**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003900000001000000) may provide a more suitable approach.

Comment: The order of features after an operation is completely arbitrary but if you do the same operation with the same inputs you will get the same outputs. Is it important to have the split line segments in order from start to finish in the attribute table? I think a picture might help explain your concern, can you get a labelled screen shot to expand your question with more clarity please.

Comment: Along the same lines as the two above comments, is there an attribute in the layer that would define some sort of order? Records in a table have no inherent order - they show up according to whatever field sort is currently applied, which is *usually* objectID at first/by default (usually ordered the same as records were added to the database) but not always. How your split operation functions may alter the OID sequence significantly, but OID doesn't really mean anything *except in that table*.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, it is important to have the split line segments in order from start to finish, because after I would like to calculate some statistics.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no identification attribute to sort in the correct form.

Comment: I don't have the license level to run the split line by points tool so I used the free version of [ET GeoWizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/) and that generated the split lines in order. But I was careful to digitize some points along a polyline in the correct sequence. It is not clear from your description if your points have been digitized in sequence or they are labelled with an ID which is sequential. If your ID is indicative of sequence maybe you can run some sort of Table sort and use that as input into the split tool?

Comment: @Hornbydd: Sorry for forgetting to comment that. I have 500 points and they are not a result of sequence generation. The final length of each segement is between 60 and 600 meters.

Comment: About ET GeoWizard. I can not use it without a license, because of the high number (500 points).

Comment: So your points were not generated sequentially but they are labelled sequential,  is this correct?  Try sorting by your Id field before using the split tool?

Comment: For clarification, just sorting the attribute table is unlikely to change the outcome. However, there is a Sort (Data Management) tool that will actually reorder the records in the database. That relies on having an attribute on which to sort, so if your points were in no way sequential it will do no good. @Hornbydd just used ET because he didn't have Split, but it sounds like your data is different than his test so it wouldn't matter - Arc's Split may work the same way. Otherwise you could split your data into groups of 100 for temporary use of ET.

Comment: It sounds like altering or restatement of your question might be in order. Assuming Arc Split works like ET, you need sequential points. If your points are not in any sort of order, then using linear referencing with your line may allow you to create an order to them, which you could then Sort the records on. The other approach is to change the question to 'sort line segments in order from one end to the other of their parent line by geometry rather than attribute'. You have sort of already stated this but may want to change the actual question since that just talks about splitting a line.

Comment: The labels you can see in the maps are Object IDs. So, unfortunately there is no other ID for sorting.

Comment: Maybe, I did not exactly comment others details of the points. The points start at the lines beginning and go geographically sorted to the lines end.

Comment: If the second image is showing your point object IDs, they appear to be sequential - does that not hold the entire length? If it does, that indicates the Arc Split does *not* output the right sequence and ET does. You could try exporting the first 99 and using ET to split. If the result works, just do it in batches. The answer to 2) in your question is that not all segments have the same direction - some end or begin at the same point rather than going start to end/start next. You would need to flip the lines going the 'wrong' direction for that method to work.